# Existence of certain surfaces in flat riemannian 3-manifold

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed orientable connected riemannian $3$-manifold (closed means compact and without boundary).

Is the following affirmation true?

Afirmação: If $(M,g)$ is flat, then there is a closed orientable connected surface $\Sigma$ embedded in $M$ such that $\Sigma$ has positive genus and the induced homomorphism in the fundamental groups by inclusion $i:\Sigma\rightarrow M$ is injective.

Comment: Thurston's geometrization tells you that $M$ should be mapping torus of finite automorphism group of $T^2$. So you can always find an incompressible torus there which has positive genus

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee Can you point me any reference?